# Is jQuery.one() possibly a bad idea for attaching multiple event handlers?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, onkeydown, onkeypress

There is an `<input type="text">` on a form and when I click it to give it focus and I start typing the first char I enter is ignored. The input starts filling from the second on.

**There must be something in the page that is consuming the first char. How can I find what that is?**

Even if I click the input several times before typing, the first char gets slurped.

The only peculiarities I am aware of in this situation are:

- beforehand there was a `<div class="overlay">` covering the whole page. The
  overlay went into `display:none;` with a click. I have tried
  deleting the div using the devTools, in case it was still intercepting stuff, but the problem remained
- the tabindex properties of the form have been manipulated with jQuery instructions

I have verified the problem in Chrome37, IE11 and FF32.

Comment: Can you create a demo (e.g. jsfiddle)? Impossible to know what is affecting the code without seeing or experiencing it.

Comment: There's too much code involved. And I am afraid my company won't allow me to do that. This question is aimed at collecting ideas on how to tackle a problem with unknown event handlers in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the bug. Let's put the solution here and change the question title, because it is interesting...

Going through the code for the tenth time (someone else's code obviously...) I observe the peculiar way the event handler got attached:

```
$(document).one("keydown mousedown touchstart", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  self.hideOverlayDiv();
})
```

`$.one` is used, probably trying to avoid to have to remove explicitly the event handler after the run.

Problem is: after I consume the `mousedown` event handler, there are two more event handlers ready to run on `keydown` and `touchstart` events. And when I begin filling the input, the `onkeydown` fella slurps my first char.

I have changed the thing like this:

```
$(document).on("keydown mousedown touchstart", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  self.hidePopupError();
  $(document).off("keydown mousedown touchstart");
})
```